# how to change error message for not allowed htttp methods when calling an API resource in wso2 API manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I created a rest api in wso2 api manager publisher add add a resource for example delivery and only assign post method for calling this api resource , by default when use other http methods for calling this api , api manager throws below response :

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
  <am:code>405</am:code>
  <am:type>Status report</am:type>
  <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
  <am:description>Method not allowed for given API resource</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

and in some http methods like COPY it throws 400 bad request ,first I want to don't show above message in response and only give back the status code and nothing in response message
and second show 405 method not allowed for all http methods except POST method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the default fault sequence in order the change the message. Take a look at [this document](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/troubleshooting/error-handling/#custom-error-messages).

Comment: thanx o much 
I have another question , some http methods for example copy return 400 bad request , I want to set it to method not allowed in fault sequence , how to do this?

Comment: @Alifarahzadi WSO2 doesn't seem to support these HTTP methods. Hence it would be tricky to handle these. Maybe you can try creating a custom handler.

Comment: can you provide a link to documentation?

Comment: @Alifarahzadi https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/develop/extending-api-manager/extending-gateway/writing-custom-handlers/ 
I'm not sure it would work, Probably the request will fail before reaching the handler. But give it a try.